# to retrieve checkbox value from mysql

Tags: javascript, html, css

how could i print the full textarea contents in the print  without any scroll bars......i mean when i enter the contents in the textarea only the last few lines of the text area are being displayed for the print.....i actually need all the contents that is being entered text area to be printed........i.e the textarea should be auto resizeed for the print

```
<textarea class="notes1" style="height:150px;width:90%;" style="width:90%;border-height=150px;border-width:2px;" id="remarks" name="remarks" form="saveref"  required></textarea>
```

.....this the textarea code that is being used and the css for the print  is....

```
textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden;  resize: none; }
```

Comment: is the title of the question related to your content?

Comment: mysql? so why you tagged `js` `html` `css` ?!

Comment: Your question is different and other content are different, what you want?

Comment: how is mysql related to this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it only with CSS, use print media query.

```
@media print {
    textarea {
        height: //set to to max height you want
    }
}
```

Comment: nope sir this ain't working....if i enter 8 lines of data ( the textarea height to be set to 150px) only the last 5 lines are being displayed fro the print  .... already .tried

Comment: i actually need the textarea to be resized for print purpose...........and that displays all the lines of data that is being entered

Comment: Change your question first.